# Group and combine value DataTable sizeable Columns, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, schedule

I'm facing with the DataTable. How can I group it by multiple columns and combine the Data, Count as well.
It's quite complicated, I have to make a sample excel in Google Drive. Hope everyone understand.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NiAuTvzYEECmvBn6eLNeBFpjslj6pmG7fZe-h-g6cRU/edit#gid=0

Rule:

- "Id" Column: Combine value after group
- "Count" Column: sum Id after group
- Others: If same value : show value, else : value = string.empty;

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.
group by Category.

```
DataTable dtCategory = new DataTable();
        dtCategory.Columns.Add("ID");
        dtCategory.Columns.Add("Category");
        dtCategory.Columns.Add("Type");
        dtCategory.Columns.Add("Parameter1");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var vCategory = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             group x by x.Field<string>("Category") into grp
                             select new
                             {
                                 Category = grp.Key,
                                 grp
                             }).ToList();
            foreach (var singleCatagory in vCategory)
            {
                List<int> singleCatagoryList = singleCatagory.grp.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();
                dtCategory.Rows.Add(string.Join(",", singleCatagoryList),singleCatagory.Category);
            }
        }
```

group by category and type

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var vCategory = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 group x by new
                                 {
                                     Category = x.Field<string>("Category"),
                                     Type = x.Field<int>("Type")
                                 }
                                 into grp
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     grp.Key.Category,
                                     grp.Key.Type,
                                     grp
                                 }).ToList();
                foreach (var singleCatagory in vCategory)
                {
                    List<int> singleCatagoryList = singleCatagory.grp.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();
                    dtCategory.Rows.Add(string.Join(",", singleCatagoryList), singleCatagory.Category, singleCatagory.Type);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

***I created a dummy data which is the same from your sample data***

```
        DataTable dtNew, dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Category",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Type",typeof(string));
        dtNew = dt.Clone();


        dt.Rows.Add("323021", "Doors", "900");
        dt.Rows.Add("323022", "Doors", "900");
        dt.Rows.Add("323023", "Doors", "1000");
        dt.Rows.Add("323024", "Doors", "1000");

        dt.Rows.Add("323025", "Walls", "200");
        dt.Rows.Add("323026", "Walls", "200");
        dt.Rows.Add("323027", "Walls", "200");
        dt.Rows.Add("323028", "Walls", "200");

        dt.Rows.Add("323026", "Columns", "300x300");
        dt.Rows.Add("323027", "Columns", "300x300");
        dt.Rows.Add("323028", "Columns", "500x500");
```

**Solution for Case: Category**

```
        //Case 1: Category
        var caretoryResult = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(category => category.Field<string>("Category")).ToList();
        foreach (var item in caretoryResult)
        {
            var getType = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(type => type.Field<string>("Category").Trim() == item.Key.ToString().Trim());
            dtNew.Rows.Add("", "", "");

            string[] strType = new string[getType.ToList().Count];
            int b = 0;
            getType.ToList().ForEach(row => { 
                dtNew.Rows[dtNew.Rows.Count - 1]["Id"] += row.Field<string>("Id").Trim() + ",";
                strType[b++] = row.Field<string>("Type").Trim();
            });
            dtNew.Rows[dtNew.Rows.Count - 1]["Category"] = item.Key.ToString().Trim();
            dtNew.Rows[dtNew.Rows.Count - 1]["Type"] = strType.ToList().GroupBy(type => type).ToList().Count > 1 ? "" : strType[0].Trim();
        }
```

**Solution for Case: Category and Type**

```
        //Case 1: Category and Type
        var caretoryTypeResult = (from b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                              group b by new
                              {
                                  Category = b.Field<string>("Category"),
                                  Type = b.Field<string>("Type")
                              }
                                  into grpCategoryType
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      grpCategoryType.Key.Category,
                                      grpCategoryType.Key.Type,
                                      grpCategoryType
                                  }).ToList();

        caretoryTypeResult.ForEach(list => {
            var category = list.grpCategoryType.AsEnumerable().Select(m => m.Field<string>("Id")).ToList();
            dtNew.Rows.Add(string.Join(",", category), list.Category, list.Type);

        });
```

Hope this code helps

Comment: By the way use the dtNew for final result. Thanks